# Is it possible for a solution of a nonlinear differential equation to be written as a sum of linear basis functions in a Hilbert Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

On the one hand, I think that there are nonlinear differential equations where you can show the solution is not linear. However, I think that solutions to differential equations must be contained in a Hilbert space, meaning that this "vector" can be written in terms of basis vectors of that Hilbert space.